# Can you find your android when the phones off

Tags: lost-phone

I lost my android, can it be found in the apartments when the phones off?

Comment: Only when you know where to look, I'm afraid.

Comment: Of course it can be found. The question is how?

Comment: Only this app can answer the question: [Ask Jesus](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rodi.andrey.android.AskJesus&hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, if the phone is turned off there is no way **for a consumer** to locate it without an external tag or similar product. Law enforcement may have methods beyond the reach of the general public, but I do not know how these work.

Answer (score -1):

The country I live in can find phones even after Switching Off. They use IMEI numbers to track down the location of the phone. We just need to report to the police and file a case and make official statement.

And if you have installed a good antivirus it will message your contacts as soon as someone inserts a new SIM card.

Comment: I very much doubt your country can find switched-off phones by IMEI. It is possible to locate a device by IMEI if it's powered up and logged into a mobile network – but not with the device switched off (I'd really like to see a reference on that). All that can be done is to tell the last location of *before* it was powered off, at best. Also, an "antivirus" has nothing to do with sending messages when a SIM was inserted.